# What is the difference between the 3 architectural components of Microsoft R Server?

Tags: r

Lately, I've been experimenting with Microsoft R Server(MRS) and SQL Server R Services. I've come across that MRS is built on architectural components like **ScaleR** algorithms optimized for fast parallel execution, **DistributedR** parallel computing framework for managing compute resources, and **ConnectR** for versatile connections to data sources.


I've also learnt (and got confused) that

- **ScaleR** algorithms are basically functions of the **RevoScaleR package** built on the **DistributedR** framework.
- **ConnectR** component of the architecture is also a bunch of **RevoScaleR** functions / adapters to access a variety of data sources.

My question is:
What is **RevoScaleR** in relation to **DistributedR** and **ConnectR**?

Where does **DeployR** fit into all this?


In general, I want to know the high level differences between
**RevoScaleR package**
**DistributedR**
**ScaleR**
**ConnectR**
**DeployR**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RevoScaleR package & ScaleR are same (I think after MS acquisition its became scaleR) 
A new file format especially designed for large files such as : 
XDF File Format (block based data format)
RxDataSource (designed to support the use of external memory algorithms with .xdf files.)
PEMA  based Algorithms
External memory implementations of the statistical algorithms most commonly used with large data sets such as : rxSummary, rxCrossTabs, rxLinMod. rxKMeans, rxGlm etc.
An extensible programming framework that allows R programmers to write their own external memory algorithms that can take advantage of ScaleR Enterprise’s new Big Data capabilities.

DistributedR for supporting big data framework
ConnectR It has all connectors to interact with other data sources
DeployR is used to integrate R with any application programming

Comment: So, is ConnectR a bunch of ScaleR functions (RxDataSource with extensions) that act as adapters to connect to data from SAS, SPSS, Hadoop, Teradata, other ODBCs etc?  

And can DeployR capability be used to integrate/connect to PowerBI or Visual Studio?